# Using 'No' in Angular ng-show

Tags: angularjs

So I have this piece of code. This element should be shown if the model optionFalse is set, and if not it will not be shown:

```
<input ng-show="optionFalse" type="radio" name="example_boolean" />{% verbatim %}{{ optionFalse }}{% endverbatim %}
```

The way I set the optionFalse value is via ng-model:

```
 <input ng-model="optionFalse" type="text" name="answer_opt_true" value="" />
```

So if I type something it the text input the radio should appear. It works fine with every keyword, but when I type 'No' the input doesn't appear. Why is that? Is somehow No evaluated to false? If it is so, how can I find a workaround?

The same behaviour is happening when I type 'n'. With othe letters works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular binds `ng-show` to a boolean value. It needs to be `true` for an element to show.

> Note: Here is a list of values that ngShow will consider as a falsy
>   value (case insensitive): "f" / "0" / "false" / "no" / "n" / "[]"

taken from [AngularJs docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)

Comment: Also: here is the [pertinent function on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/834d316829afdd0cc6a680f47d4c9b691edcc989/src/Angular.js#L962)

Comment: Sometimes people forget that a not empty string evaluates to true e.g. !!'false' == true. But (false == 'no') is much less obvious implicit type casting.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the length of a text in the input ?

EDIT: Just check the length of the input like in this [example](http://jsbin.com/uSABApi/36/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: You should ask questions in the comments section of the question

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my not so smart answer was a bit ambiguous. Will try to express my thoughts more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the test explicit so that it shows for other falsy values. Like, this will work for `no`

```
<input ng-show="optionFalse != null" type="radio" name="example_boolean" />{% verbatim %}{{ optionFalse }}{% endverbatim %}
```

or

```
<input ng-show="optionFalse != ''" type="radio" name="example_boolean" />{% verbatim %}{{ optionFalse }}{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of values mentioned before are not case sensitive but are still considered falsy: "f" / "0" / "false" / "no" / "n" / "[]"

Through several of tests it can be seen when leaving a space after the actual "term", the expression will be considered as truthy. Examples: "f " / "0 " / "false " / "no " / "n " / "[] "

This can also be seen in the directive ng-if which is also dependant on truthy and falsy values